# How to force rails generator referring to simple_form 2.1.1 in gemfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

The latest simple_form is 3.0.1 and requires the following in its gemspec file:

```
  s.add_dependency('activemodel', '>= 4.0.0', '< 4.1')
  s.add_dependency('actionpack', '>= 4.0.0', '< 4.1')
```

When installing simple_form 2.1.1, the rails generator `rails generator simple_form:install` caused the error:

```
:in `raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate simple_form-3.0.1, because activemodel-3.2.15 conflic
ts with activemodel (< 4.1, >= 4.0.0), actionpack-3.2.15 conflicts with actionpack (< 4.1, >= 4.0.0) (Gem::LoadError)
```

The rails generator is referring to the latest simple_form 3.0.1 which requires rails 4 or above (we are using rails 3.2.12). Even though simple_form 2.1.1 is specified in gemspec file, it did not stop rails generator referring to 3.0.1. How to force rails generator for  simple_form only refer the version 2.1.1 which is specified in gemspec file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make sure the rails generator is run in the context of the bundle, do

```
bundle exec rails generator simple_form:install
```